# Dynamic two or more levels sub-menu generation in vb6

Tags: vb6, dynamic, creation, submenu

Friends,
Tell me how to **generate more than 1 levels of sub-menu** in VB6 at runtime? Explain in brief? Any specific controls are there? But i dont want to use external controls!

Comment: If you had any code, provide me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with standard VB-menus, but since you'll have to use control arrays, you have to create a first prototype menu with `Index = 0` (e.g. `mnuFoo(0)`) at design time (usually invisible). You can now load new items dynamically.

```
Call Me.Load(mnuFoo(1)) ' New array member (index 1) '
With mnuFoo(1)
    .Visible = True ' Make it visible
    ' --- Do some settings
End With
```

Comment: I need more than one level of menu.
ie., 
a submenu and its submenu. Complete code fragment needed!

Comment: Ehm, just create your prototype menu as a submenu!

Answer (score 4):

You Can Create More than One level of Submenu by using API function

```
Private Declare Function CreatePopupMenu Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function AppendMenu Lib "user32" Alias "AppendMenuA" (ByVal hmenu As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal wIDNewItem As Long, ByVal lpNewItem As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Private Declare Function TrackPopupMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hmenu As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nReserved As Long, ByVal hwnd As Long, lprc As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function DestroyMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hmenu As Long) As Long

Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Dim hmenu As Long, hSubMenu As Long
Private Const MF_STRING = &H0&
Private Const MF_SEPARATOR = &H800&
Private Const MF_POPUP = &H10&

  hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu
  AppendMenu hSubMenu, 0, 121, "Sub Menu1"
  AppendMenu hSubMenu, 0, 122, "Sub Menu2"
  
  hmenu = CreatePopupMenu
  AppendMenu hmenu, 0, 107, "Menu1"
  
  AppendMenu hmenu, 0, 106, "Menu2"
  
  AppendMenu hmenu, MF_POPUP, hSubMenu, "Menu3"
  AppendMenu hmenu, MF_POPUP, hSubMenu, "Menu4"
  
  AppendMenu hmenu, 0, 101, "Menu5"
```

To display

```
  If Button = vbRightButton Then
    Dim P As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos P
    TrackPopupMenu hmenu, 0, P.X, P.Y, 0, hwnd, 0
```

The menu is not displayed until `TrackPopupMenu` is called. Its return value can indicate which (if any) menu item was selected. e.g., it could return '107' if "Menu1" was selected.

Comment: How to handle its events in this case?

Comment: @bjan there are no events - you just check the value of TrackPopupMenu. I've noted this in the answer.